# MYSQL using distinction but including an exemption/exclusion condition?

Tags: mysql, distinct

i am using a count query to select all non duplicate records from my table,
i'm using the following:

```
function check_profile_views3() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT profile_id) totalCOUNT2 FROM ptb_profile_views WHERE viewed_profile_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND profile_id!=".$_SESSION['user_id']."";
            $check_profile_views_set3 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($check_profile_views_set3);
            return $check_profile_views_set3;       
        }
```

my table looks like this:

```
id  |  profile_id | viewed_profile_id
1          3               6
2          3               6
3          4               6
4          -1              6
5          -1              6
```

so in this example my query selects the distinct values and doesnt count those values which are duplicates in the profile_id field,

however i now want to add an exception to this query to say count all '-1' profile id's as well as counting all distinct positive numbers.

is this possible im still learning sql so i would be really greatful if anyone can help me out.

thanks

desired result

```
the mysql table goes from this:
id | profile_id | viewed_profile_id
1        3               6
2        3               6
3        4               6
4       -1               6
5       -1               6

to this:

end result pulls results from table like this
id | profile_id | viewed_profile_id
1        3               6
2        4               6
3       -1               6
4       -1               6
```

ok so im trying JW's answer and im trying to do it like this but im going wrong somewhere:

this it how im doing the query:

```
function check_profile_views3() {
        global $connection;
        global $_SESSION;
        $query = "
        SELECT  a.*
        FROM    ptb_profile_views a
        INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  profile_id, MIN(ID) min_ID
        FROM    ptb_profile_views
        WHERE   profile_id > 0
        GROUP   BY profile_id
    ) b ON a.profile_id = b.profile_id AND
            a.ID = b.Min_ID
            UNION
            SELECT  *
            FROM    ptb_profile_views
            WHERE   profile_id < 0";
        $check_profile_views_set3 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($check_profile_views_set3);
        return $check_profile_views_set3;       
    }
```

and then im calling it on the page like so:

```
$check_profile_views_set3 = check_profile_views3();
while ($views3 = mysql_fetch_array($check_profile_views_set3)) { 

echo "". $views3['totalCOUNT2'] ."";
```

Comment: you mean count all profile id's which are -1. in your example the answer is 2 right? or the sum of viewed_profile_id ?

Comment: i want it to count all rows in the table, but i dont want positive numbers to be counted more than once hence the distinct condition, but i do want it to count all -1 values as well as the distinct positive numbers if that makes sense

Comment: add condition in where clause profile_id=-1

Comment: @shola then that will only count -1 values, but i want it to count the unique positive numbers aswel (only count the positive numbers once for each unique record)

Comment: what is your desired result?

Comment: @JW i have updated my question with the desired result please take a look

Comment: @JackHarper : means to count all positive integers once and count -ve integers twice ot thrice or ...

Comment: there is no count involve here right? I think you basically want to select only unique `profile_id` but display all `-1` id?

Comment: yes i am trying to display the total numer of profile views and i want it to show only unique profile_id's where 'profile_id' does not = '-1' but show ALL -1 profie_id's aswell and give a total of all -1's and all distinct positive values

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

SELECT viewed_profile_id,COUNT(DISTINCT profile_id) totalCOUNT2 
FROM ptb_profile_views
WHERE  profile_id not in (".$_SESSION['user_id']." ,-1)
GROUP by viewed_profile_id

Comment: Replace ".$_SESSION['user_id']."  with session user id and then try on mysql command.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT id,profile_id,viewed_profile_id 
FROM ptb_profile_views p
INNER JOIN
( SELECT MIN(id) minid FROM ptb_profile_views
  GROUP BY profile_id) x
ON p.id = x.minid
WHERE profile_id > 0
GROUP BY profile_id

UNION


SELECT id,profile_id,viewed_profile_id 
FROM ptb_profile_views 
WHERE profile_id <= 0
```

Comment: see here when I interchange the rows. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12f18/1 the result is different.

Comment: because it op is not interested on the `ID` but the count. you original answer is fine.